# Why the supplementary groups of "bash" also contains the primary group?

Tags: linux, process, group

Based on my understanding, when `bash` (or any process as long as I don't intentionally change this behavior) runs, it will have (along with other information) a list of the supplementary groups for the logged in user.

The following is the `ps` result for the supplementary groups of `bash`:

```
PID    COMMAND    SUPGRP
1409   bash       adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare chris
```

`chris` is the primary group for the logged in user, so why is it listed as part of the supplementary groups?

Comment: See also the output of `id`.

Answer (score 6):

`initgroup()`, the libc function that is typically called by *login* applications to set supplementary group list of the process it runs in your name does add the primary group id to that list.

If it didn't, that would be a security issue, as that would give you a way to relinquish access to that group by creating a setgid executable with one of your other groups, and execute that to lose your primary gid (that executable would have to call `setgid()` for the real gid to also change), which would give you access to resources that have been explicitly denied access to your primary group for instance.

Example:

```
$ ls -l file
-rw----r-- 1 root chazelas 7 Dec 12 15:33 file
```

Access has been denied to my primary gid:

```
$ cat file
cat: file: Permission denied
```

Now, let's start a shell as me where the supplementary group ids doesn't include that group to see what we could do if `login` didn't add that group to our supplementary group id list:

```
$ sudo perl -le '$( = $) =  "1000 2"; $< = $> = 1000; exec zsh'
$ ps -o rgroup,egroup,supgrp -p $$
RGROUP   EGROUP   SUPGRP
chazelas chazelas bin
$ id -a
uid=1000(chazelas) gid=1000(chazelas) groups=1000(chazelas),2(bin)
```

1000 is in gid, egid, but not the supplementary group list. As I'm also a member of `bin`, I can create a setgid `bin` executable:

```
$ cp -f /usr/bin/env .
$ chgrp bin env
$ chmod g+s env
$ ./env perl -U -le '$( = $); exec qw(/usr/bin/id -a)'
uid=1000(chazelas) gid=2(bin) groups=2(bin)
```

I'm using `perl` to call `setgid()` (`$( = $)`). And then I've lost membership of the `chazelas` group. So:

```
$ ./env perl -U -le '$( = $); exec qw(cat file)'
secret
```

By adding the group to the supplementary list, `login` makes sure you can't get out of it (as only root can change that list and it's not affected by the execution of setgid executables).

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Because something put it there. (Not very satisfactory, I know.)

POSIX take on the [`getgroups()` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getgroups.html) is that

> It is implementation-defined whether *getgroups()* also returns the effective group ID in the *grouplist* array.

On Linux (4.9), `getgroups()` doesn't include the effective GID in the returned, and neither does `/proc/$pid/status`. `ps` on Debian also doesn't seem to add it while displaying, but `id` does.

If the same GID is explicitly added with `setgroups()`, then it's listed.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

If you're looking for an explanation, man pages is always a good place to start. See `man ps`:

> supgrp      SUPGRP    group names of supplementary groups, if any. 
>   See getgroups(2).

and then, naturally, `[man getgroups][1]`:

> `getgroups()` returns the supplementary group IDs of the calling
>          process in list.  The argument size should be set to the maximum
>          number of items that can be stored in the buffer pointed to by list.
>          If the calling process is a member of more than size supplementary
>          groups, then an error results.  **It is unspecified whether the
>          effective group ID of the calling process is included in the returned list.**  (Thus, **an application should also call getegid(2) and add or remove the resulting value.**)

**Application:**

Therefore, you should `ps -eo pid,user,args,sgroup,supgrp` and possibly subtract the value in the `SGROUP` column from those in the `SUPGRP` column. This is the way to get only supplementary groups.

**Note:**

As a matter of fact, `ps` doesn't call `getgroups()`, as pointed out in the comments. See [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu)'s and [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas)'s answers which are both technically correct and well explained. This answer only wants to say that it is expected that supplementary groups *may* contain the primary group.

Comment: Well no. On Linux at least, `ps -o supgrp` does return the supplementary group list and does not include the egid there (unless it is also in the supplementary list). `ps` doesn't call `getgroups()`, the reference to `getgroups(2)` is to link to a description of the supplementary group list. If you remove the egid from the supgrp, you do not obtain the real supgrp list.