# How to empty the list of supplementary group IDs for a process?

Tags: linux, c, group

When I create a child process, it inherits the supplementary gids of the parent. If the parent is a root, then the child has (0) as supplementary gid. This behavior is not desired.

Is it possible to force supplementary group IDs to have no group id? If yes, how?

Comment: Why was the question tagged with "C"? Are you writing a program to do something? How would you have a group with no group ID? What would the purpose be?

Comment: Are you asking about dropping group privileges  in a C program?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Because I am using the c language. When I create a child process, it inherits the supplementary gids of the parent. If the parent is a root, then the child has (0) as supplementary gid. This behavior is not desired

Comment: @Kusalananda yes!

Comment: The duplicate does, but the ways to do that invariably (I have just checked my, Daniel J. Bernstein's, Gerrit Pape's, and Laurent Bercot's tools.) use a supplementary groups list of minimum length 1.  We have questions and answers on how to do that, and about why that's the convention (e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410415/), but I don't see one asking whether it is possible to create, and how to go about creating, a process with an _empty_ supplementary groups set.